# build failed for datastax spark-cassandra connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, sbt, spark-cassandra-connector

I was trying to build the spark-cassandra connector and followed this link :

```
http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/kindling-an-introduction-to-spark-with-cassandra/
```

Which further in the link asks to download the connector from git and build using sbt. But, when i try to run the command `./sbt/sbt assembly`. It throws the following exception :

```
Launching sbt from sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.8.jar
[info] Loading project definition from /home/naresh/Desktop/spark-cassandra-connector/project
Using releases: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2 for releases
Using snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots for snapshots

  Scala: 2.10.5 [To build against Scala 2.11 use '-Dscala-2.11=true']
  Scala Binary: 2.10
  Java: target=1.7 user=1.7.0_79

[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/home/naresh/Desktop/spark-cassandra-connector/)
    [warn] Credentials file /home/hduser/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
    [warn] Credentials file /home/hduser/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
    [warn] Credentials file /home/hduser/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
    [warn] Credentials file /home/hduser/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
    [warn] Credentials file /home/hduser/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
    [info] Compiling 140 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/naresh/Desktop/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector/target/scala-2.10/classes...
    [error] /home/naresh/Desktop/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra/CassandraCatalog.scala:48: not found: value processTableIdentifier
    [error]     val id = processTableIdentifier(tableIdentifier).reverse.lift
    [error]              ^
    [error] /home/naresh/Desktop/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra/CassandraCatalog.scala:134: value toSeq is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.TableIdentifier
    [error]     cachedDataSourceTables.refresh(tableIdent.toSeq)
    [error]                                               ^
    [error] /home/naresh/Desktop/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra/CassandraSQLContext.scala:94: not found: value BroadcastNestedLoopJoin
    [error]       BroadcastNestedLoopJoin
    [error]       ^
    [error] three errors found
    [info] Compiling 11 Scala sources to /home/naresh/Desktop/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector-embedded/target/scala-2.10/classes...
    [warn] /home/naresh/Desktop/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector-embedded/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/embedded/SparkTemplate.scala:69: value actorSystem in class SparkEnv is deprecated: Actor system is no longer supported as of 1.4.0
    [warn]   def actorSystem: ActorSystem = SparkEnv.get.actorSystem
    [warn]                                               ^
    [warn] one warning found
    [error] (spark-cassandra-connector/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
    [error] Total time: 27 s, completed 4 Nov, 2015 12:34:33 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,
 run `mvn -DskipTests clean package`

- you can find `build spark command` in `README.md` file from your spark Dir.
- Before run that command You’ll need to configure Maven to use more
  memory than usual by setting MAVEN_OPTS
  `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"`

Comment: I am building it for scala using sbt not through maven